# having issue in configuring server from rails with bigblue button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, bigbluebutton

am developing an app in which am integarating my rails app with bigblue button. I am using bigbluebutton_rails gem. I have installed the gem, then i have done

```
  rails generate bigbluebutton_rails:install
```

then, i have generated the views, after this i got all the views, controllers and models.
After this i tried to access bigbluebutton conference from my app, so i tried to create a server but i couldnt configure server of bigblue button in this form[image]

i didn't know what should i enter in this form.

How i can create, join and use the conference from here. could any one help me out of this??

Answer (score 0):

You need a BigBlueButton server installed somewhere (see how to do it in https://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/Installation). You will then configure your Rails application to create meetings in this BigBlueButton server. They are separate things, you will have 2 servers: a BigBlueButton (web conference) server and a web application written in Rails that access the BigBlueButton server.

The information you need to enter in the form from your screenshot is:

- Name: Any string to name your server.
- URL: The URL of your BigBlueButton server's API, for example: `http://my-server.org/bigbluebutton/api`.
- Security salt: The salt, or shared secret, of your BigBlueButton server. You can get it running this command in your BigBlueButton server (version 0.81): `bbb-conf --salt`.
- Version: The version of your BigBlueButton server (the latest is 0.81). The supported versions are described in BigbluebuttonRails' wiki: https://github.com/mconf/bigbluebutton_rails#supported-versions
- String ID: The identifier for this server, used in URLs and other places.